# Phonegap Build 3.1 to 3.3 iOS not firing deviceready

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I tried everything ... I even build Demo Apps, but I don't get the device ready callback on my iPhone 5S

The Javascript Code looks like this

```
        function onBodyLoad() {
                  document.addEventListener("deviceready",
                    onDeviceReady, false);
                }

function onDeviceReady() {
            alert("ready");
    }
```

and the HTML looks like this

```
<html>
  <head>

    <script src="js/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ratchet.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body onload="onBodyLoad()">


<div class="content">
Blabla
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

I've also added the Device Plugin for Cordova / Phonegap in the config.xml.

```
 <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
```

I don't use Xcode or anything else. Sorry, but i'm a complete newbie to this. Being a designer i was just looking for a quick way to do apps. Which i kinda found, but as you can see with some problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least based on the code above, you didn't include the call to cordova.js:

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Comment: Because, as i read, it's implemented by Phonegap build... but i will try.

Comment: Thank you ... totally misunderstood the documentation at this point. They stated to "not include the javascript" itself, not meaning "not including the reference". Thank you Raymond!